What is the difference between math/big Set() and using direct assignment?
The math/big Set() function is defined as
func (z *big.Int) Set(x *big.Int) *big.Int
Set sets z to x and returns z.

What is the difference to doing a direct assignment like
newBig := big.NewInt(0)
myVar := newBig

Is it just that Set() also returns z, or is there other pointer voodoo going on here?
I would expect that if I used
myVar.Set(newBig) 

myVar would contain a pointer to the memory address of the value where newBig is also pointing to, correct?

"myVar := newBig" just copies the pointer. You now have two variables pointing to the same big.Int; not two big.Ints with the same value. Please take the Tour of Go to learn about the fundamentals of how pointers behave.

And even if you dereference the pointer to copy the struct, you will end up sharing the internal slice, which is why the Set() method exists, and why the documentation says 'To "copy" an Int value, an existing (or newly allocated) Int must be set to a new value using the Int.Set method; shallow copies of Ints are not supported and may lead to errors.'

No, they are different:
    newBig := big.NewInt(42)
    myVar := newBig

Here, you just aliased myVar to newBig, they both point to the same value.
    otherVar := new(big.Int).Set(newBig)

otherVar is a new value with a copy of the value in newBig.
    newBig.SetInt64(24)

Here we change newBig (and myVar, since it's aliased), otherVar is not affected.
    fmt.Printf("myVar=%v, otherVar=%v\n", myVar, otherVar)

Prints “myVar=24, otherVar=42”, try it on the Go playground. Also, there are some pretty good examples in the documentation.

Many thanks, that is very useful. The way how I see it (and please correct me if I am wrong): Aliasing is not bad per se - it is just that you have to know what you are doing. If you are sure the value will never be changed again by any other pointer pointing to it, or you are fine with that and even want that change to be reflected in your alias, then you are safe. In case of doubt, it is safer to copy the value.

Copying is usually cheap - otherwise you have to copy the pointer. Aliasing is not bad per se - you use it when you call a function with a pointer. The effects are often surprising (see my example, why did myVar change) and hard to debug.
